# Executing stored procedures in parallel.foreach .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, linq, parallel.foreach

I need to run 4 stored procedured and create queries from data received. There is about 5k items in q container co it is 20k executions of stored procedures. I use LINQ to connect to DB and execute them and it works just great with normal foreach loop but there is one problem: code takes about one hour to complete. It is way to long so I tried to write Parrarel.ForEach instead of normal ForEach loop. Code crashes after few iterations - I guess LINQ connection just doesnt get on with Parrarel. Any ideas how to run LINQ stored procedures in multiple Threads?

```
var dataCollector = new EpmDataCollector();
Parallel.ForEach(q, history =>
{                    
try
{  
        var queriesBefore = dataCollector.GetQueries().Count;
        var weight = dataCollector.CreateProjectQuery(history);//function executes stored procedure and creates queries from data received, then adds them to container (ConcurrentBag) in dataCollector
        dataCollector.CreateHoursQuery(history);//like above
        dataCollector.CreateCostQuery(history);//same
        dataCollector.CreateIncomeQuery(history);//same                    

        var log = ...
        Global.log.Info(log);

        //i++;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            //calculate and log estimation time
        } 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //catch code
}
});
```

Comment: Yeah; create new linq context inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I also tried to lock dataCollector but it seems to do nothing then.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar then i got AggregateException in SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun

Comment: Aggregate exception generally means "something went wrong in one ore more threads". List of exceptions under the aggregate exception contains the important stuff - so what's there ? If you want help you have to be as descriptive as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

`System.Data.Linq.DataContext` class is not thread safe.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx

> Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

That's why you have to create new instance of `DataContext` within the `ForEach` loop.

Also I'd rather look into `SqlBulkCopy` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) which is specifically designed to handle thousands of inserts.

Comment: I dont need to insert data. I execute stored procedures and work on data received

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of your EpmDataCollector into the loop like so:

```
Parallel.ForEach(q, history =>
{                    
try
{  
        var dataCollector = new EpmDataCollector();
        var queriesBefore = dataCollector.GetQueries().Count;
        var weight = dataCollector.CreateProjectQuery(history);//function executes stored procedure and creates queries from data received, then adds them to container (ConcurrentBag) in dataCollector
        dataCollector.CreateHoursQuery(history);//like above
        dataCollector.CreateCostQuery(history);//same
        dataCollector.CreateIncomeQuery(history);//same                    

        var log = ...
        Global.log.Info(log);

        //i++;
        Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            //calculate and log estimation time
        } 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //catch code
}
});
```